# Convert image to sepia tone

Tags: c#, image

I have code in C# to convert to sepia tone from Image:

```
for ( int y = startY; y < stopY; y++ )
{
      // for each pixel
      for ( int x = startX; x < stopX; x++, ptr += pixelSize )
      {
           t = (byte) ( 0.299 * ptr[RGB.R] + 0.587 * ptr[RGB.G] + 0.114 * ptr[RGB.B] );

           // red
           ptr[RGB.R] = (byte) ( ( t > 206 ) ? 255 : t + 49 );
           // green
           ptr[RGB.G] = (byte) ( ( t < 14 ) ? 0 : t - 14 );
           // blue
           ptr[RGB.B] = (byte) ( ( t < 56 ) ? 0 : t - 56 );
       }
       ptr += offset;
}
```

But I don't understand about values: 206, 14, 56. Why use this values? Please explain for me.

Thanks!

Comment: those are RED(R) GREEN(G) BLUE(B)  values , you should remeber that any color is combination of these 3 colors ranging from 0-255.

Comment: Is this algorhitm not working for you?

Comment: It's RGB value and it are represented by numbers between 0 and 255

Comment: It's just transformation of one (normal) hue graph into another (sepia) one. Those number move the axis for each RGB value to the left (right). Those values are empiric. Try and change them to get another kind of transformation.

Comment: The 206, 14, and 56 are to make sure that `t` isn't greater than 255 (for red since you add 49 [`49+206=255`]) or less than 0 (for green and blue [since you subtract 14 and 56]). You are probably adding to the red and subtracting from the green and blue because a sepia tone is slightly red.

Answer (score 0):

The colors are represented using 3 color channels: red, green and blue. Each channel can have 256 different shades, going from 0 to 255.

The numbers 206, 14, and 56 are being used as cut-off points to give a sepia look to the image when converting it to sepia. For example, in the blue channel and shade of blue below 56 is mapped to 0 (black), otherwise the blues are shifted downwards slighly towards black. The reds are set to white for any shade above 206, otherwise they are shifted towards white.

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the tone of the image by adding 49 to red, and substracting 14 and 56 from green and blue respectively, which will change the tone to more sepia-like. Since you cannot set the pixel color value to less than 0 or more than 255, they're being clipped, so the limits are not exceeded.